# jenkins - version placeholder from previous build POM

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

once created a job in jenkins, I want to create a parametrized build. One of the parameters is version, which I set manually. But before I set it I want to see project version from POM from last successful build as placeholder.

something like:

---

next version:

$PREVIOUS_VERSION_AS_PLACEHOLDER

set up next version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a system groovy script that would change the default value of your parameter on each run. for example:

(assuming your parameter name is "PREVIOUS_VERSION_AS_PLACEHOLDER")

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*

def job = build.getParent() // get the job object
paramsDef = job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class) // get the parameters definition object
if (paramsDef) {
        paramsDef.parameterDefinitions.each { param ->
            if ("PREVIOUS_VERSION_AS_PLACEHOLDER".equals(param.name)) {
                def value = <the_new_version_in_the_pom.xml_file>
                println("INFO: Changing parameter ${param.name} default value (was ${param.defaultValue}) to ${value}")
                param.defaultValue = value
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it work before the job starts? this seems like it would work after i set the params. I'm not proficient with groovy, so don't know.

Comment: it is part of the job. the idea is that it updates your job parameter for the next run. note that you still need to read the version from the file and pass it to the script.